# is there a new command for "from pandas_datareader import data as web"?

Tags: pandas

This is giving an error:

ImportError: cannot import name PandasError

Is there now a new command for calling the data object from pandas "from pandas_datareader import data as web"?

Comment: What version is your pandas? That command refers to later versions: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html are you following the guidelines in that link?

Comment: python 2.7...not sure about pandas ver